# How to extract a substring from a column of strings if it matches a given value?

Tags: r, substring

I'm trying to extract a substring from a string for each row in a column if it matches a specific value. Subsequently I want to add the matched substring to a new column. The substring must match either `'GET'`, `'POST'` or `'HEAD'`. The strings are in the following format: `'GET /icons/circle_logo_small.gif'`.

This is my current dataframe

[image: current df]

And this the expected dataframe

[image: expected df]

Comment: Add data in text form, not images. Please follow here to learn more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Comment: I don't see your code. Did you try `?substring`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract all strings before `space`.
One way:

```
df$Category <- gsub( " .*$", "", df$request )
```

Assuming `df` is your dataframe